# Compact Framework 3.5 override ListView

Tags: c#, listview, overriding, barcode-scanner

I have barcode scanner application written on C#
based on Compact Framework 3.5.
I created ListViewEx Object inherited from ListView for my forms. 
But when i try override method 
public virtual int Add(ColumnHeader value); which exists in Original ListView, i get error, "no suitable method found to override"

```
public class ListViewEx : ListView
{
    public override int Add(ColumnHeader value)
        {
            base.Add(value);
            value.Text = Translations.TranslateText(value.Text);
        }
}
```

As I read Parent method must be marked as virtual and must have same signature to be available for override so does method from Original ListView:

```
 public virtual int Add(ColumnHeader value);
```

Any ideas what can be a problem?
I googled some answers on this question, but they advised to change entire code and original Parent class what I in this situation can`t do.

Or may be override is denied in Compact Framework?